# Doesn't Det Arthur Bell know his Nikon camera has LCD display?

Tags: orphan-black

In S2E4 Orphan Black, Det Arthur Bell is snooping around the Prolethean campus taking pictures with his expensive Nikon camera.

Doesn't he know his Nikon camera has LCD display?

[image]

Comment: Um... does it matter? Most photographers prefer using the viewfinder over using live view... in fact, I don't know any photographers who use live view instead of the viewfinder.  I have a Nikon D90 that has an LCD but I never use it unless I can't get my head to the viewfinder due to the angle of the shot.

Comment: Like when you are snooping around, you'd deliberately show that you are shooting the scenery?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: No, he obviously didn't notice it. It's pretty subtle, right? Easy to miss. Is this really a question?

Answer (score 4):

I have no clue whether he "knows it has an LCD" or not.  What I can tell you is that photographers generally don't use LCDs when shooting unless they have no choice in the matter due to the angle you're shooting.

People used to shooting on phones or point and shoot cameras get really used to shooting using LCDs but there are many downsides to using them:

LCDs can be very difficult to see in different lighting situations while the dark space behind the viewfinder is always a controlled space with only the actual light being seen.

In addition to that, the LCD image is not always as clear as actually looking through the lens. The pixel ratio on those LCDs is generally pretty low, so the resolution is terrible for anything other than text and quickly viewing images after the fact.

In addition to that, LCDs kill battery life. In normal conditions, you might be able to use a camera for 6 hours of consistent shooting but, with the LCD, you'd drop to an hour or two.

Answer (score 1):

Ahah the scenes with the Nikon camera are so bad! The producers obviously never shot a Nikon DSLR or any DSLR before. The display is all messed up. It's on auto ISO but it stays at ISO 200 all the time while it is underexposed and there is no exposure compensation.. also, the viewfinder should be black when he presses the shutter because the mirror is going up. His settings are always the same in all the scenes. The white balance is set to tungsten wich is wrong for an overcast day. If there is only one thing right, it's that he is looking down the viewfinder and not the screen like a rookie would do. Source: I'm a professional photographer.

Comment: "Professionals" don't know how to handle technology. Sometimes  engineers design a particular feature that we had presumed people, especially "professionals" know how to use, they don't. Only another engineer would know why it's there and know how to use it. But they still sit on their laurels as being "professionals".

Comment: Yes, the question is not very good, but calm down. I think the real answer is that taking a photo is supposed to look like that TV, it just looks better that way. The detective is not trying to capture "artistic scenery", but rather just collect information - either method would suffice?